# Efficiently calculating comparisons between finite mixtures of Gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution, mixture-distribution

Say I have two finite mixtures, each consisting of an equally weighted mix of $n$ Gaussians each with a known mean and standard deviation.

Is there an efficient method of calculating the probability that a random sample drawn from the first is less than a random sample drawn from the second?

The naive method is simple: enumerate all pairs of Gaussians choosing one from each mixture, [calculate the result for the pair](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/40236/246278), and take the mean.

This works, but is $O(n^2)$. Is there a more efficient method of calculating this?

Comment: As an aside, I had a very hard time trying to figure out which site to post this question on. It's a programming question. Wait, it's a asymptotic complexity theory question! Wait, it's a math question! Wait, it's a stats question!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X_1<X_2) &= \mathbb E[\mathbb I_{X_1<X_2}]\\
 &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E\{\mathbb I_{X_1<X_2}|Z_1,Z_2\}]\\
 &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E\{\mathbb I_{X_1-X_2+\mu_{2Z_2}-\mu_{1Z_1}<\mu_{2Z_2}-\mu_{1Z_1}}|Z_1,Z_2\}]\\                   
   &= \mathbb E[\Phi(\{\mu_{2Z_2}-\mu_{1Z_1}\}/\{\sigma^2_{2Z_2}+\sigma^2_{1Z_1}\}^{1/2})]
\end{align*}
when denoting the labels by $Z_1$ and $Z_1$, resp., and $\mu_{ij},\sigma_{ij}$ the parameters of the respective Normal components. Unless the terms
$$\{\mu_{2j}-\mu_{1k}\}/\{\sigma^2_{2j}+\sigma^2_{1k}\}^{1/2}$$
are identical for several pairs $(j,k)$, it is alas a computation of order $O(n^2)$. Due to the equally weighted components, simulation would not bring much of an improvement unless $n$ is very large and components can start being neglected.

This probability can also be written as
$$\mathbb E[F_X(Y)]=\int F_X(y) f_Y(y)\,\text dy$$
but the integrand is again of order $O(n^2)$.

Comment: One could make the same argument about Fourier transforms, and yet FFTs exist...

Comment: Thanks for the proper notation, by the way. It's been way too long since university.